# Не могу объединить множества

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
   'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
   'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}

for i in ids.values():
  i1 = set(i)
  print(i1.intersection(i1))
```

Как объединить множества, метод intersection не помогает. Выводит:

```
{213, 15}
{54, 119}
{98, 35, 213}
```

А нужно     `{213, 15, 54, 119, 98, 35}`

Comment: intersection - это пересечение, а не объединение. Объединение - это union. Ну и результат операции у вас никуда не сохраняется, просто выводится через print.

Comment: union дает тот же самый ответ, я не понимаю где ошибка

Comment: `set(chain.from_iterable(ids.values()))`. [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все таки применить нужно метод изменяющий множество `update`.

```py
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
    'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
    'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}
a = set()
for i in ids.values():
    i_ = set(i)
    set.update(a, i_)

print(a)

"""OUT
{98, 35, 213, 54, 119, 15}
"""
```

Методы для изменения множеств содержат [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update). Такие как

```py
update() # эквивалент |=
intersection_update() # эквивалент &=
difference_update() # эквивалент -=
```

Эквивалент в вашем случае

```py
for i in ids.values():
    a |= set(i)
```

**UPD**

Добавлю отличный вариант, указанный @SergFSM.

Можно воспользоваться оператором распаковки последовательностей - `*`.
Элегантно.

```py
a = set()
a.update(*ids.values())
```

Comment: спасибо, теперь понял

Comment: На здоровье. =)

Comment: в принципе тут и без цикла можно обойтись: `a = set() ;
a.update(*ids.values())`

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
   'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
   'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}

print({*chain.from_iterable(set(i) for i in ids.values())})


>>> {98, 35, 15, 213, 54, 119}
```

Comment: ваш способ можно упростить: `set(chain.from_iterable(ids.values()))`

Answer (score 1):

Проблемы в коде из вопроса:

1. `intersection` - это пересечение множеств (операция получения только элементов, которые есть в обоих пересекаемых множествах), вместо этого нужно `union` - объединение
2. Результат операции никуда не сохраняется, и выполняется только пересечение каждого из множеств с самим собой. Нужно инициализировать исходное множество до цикла, в которое в процессе выполнения будут "дообъединяться" элементы каждого следующего множества.

Исправление:

```
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
   'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
   'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}

result = set()

for i in ids.values():
    result = result.union(i)

print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
{98, 35, 15, 213, 54, 119}
```

Операцию `result = result.union(i)` (создание нового множества на основе старого множества и элементов из `i`) можно заменить на `result.update(i)` (добавление в исходное множество элементов из `i`), результат будет тот же самый:

```
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
   'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
   'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}

result = set()

for i in ids.values():
    result.update(i)

print(result)
```